# Rails file_field tag not showing selected file name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filefield

Even after selecting the file, rails `file_field` is not showing the selected file name.

Code:

```rb
= f.file_field :import_csv
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My First solution is to add JS.

Js Code:

```
$('#model_import_csv').on('change', (e) => {
  var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
  $('#import_csv_label').html(fileName);
});
```

Rails View Code:

```
= f.file_field :import_csv
= %label#import_csv_label
```

[image]

Hope this helped.